# Tkinter object put into list and turns into undesired tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am building a simple user interface with Tkinter.  I am getting something I have never seen before... After putting my Label objects in a list, I would expect to be able to create a for loop and then grid the labels.  When running the for loop however, I discovered my list is a list of tuples which contain the objects.  When I then get the object out of the tuple it is no longer a tk Label object.

```py
#Here are my objects being initiated before going into the list
outputdir = tk.Label(frame2, text="Output folder name"),
format = tk.Label(frame2, text="Output Format"),
compress = tk.Label(frame2, text="Compress?"),
limit_span = tk.Label(frame2, text="Limit time span?")

#The list
label_list = [outputdir, format, compress, limit_span]

#The for loop I expected to be able to use
for i in range(len(label_list)-1):
    label_obj = label_list[i]
    label_obj.grid(row=i,column=0)
```

I expected label_obj to be a tk.Label object.  What I actually get is a tuple... if I access that tuple and print I find that the object is not just a bunch of garbage numbers.

CMD output for the code I expected to work is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f9borg_ui.py", line 110, in <module>
    label_obj.grid(row=i,column=0)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Output if I print(label_list).  Notice each object is in a tuple in the list except for the last object oddly enough...

```
[(<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C328>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C3A0>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C418>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C490>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C508>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C580>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C5F8>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C670>,), (<Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C6E8>,), <Tkinter.Label instance at 0x05A4C760>]
```

Output if I access the tuple. So print(tuple_list[0][0])

```
.86381312.86381352
```

What is happening here and how can I fix this?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Remove the trailing `,` when you first initiate your labels.

Comment: @HenryYik one problem solved... no more tuples but still getting garbage when I print(label_list[0]) EDIT: never mind still works.  I'm just dumb.